# TcpClient connection error

Tags: .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

I used TcpClient and TcpListner classes for a chat application. It worked perfect on LAN. But I use same approach on internet it didn't work and gives me following error

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 112.134.252.38:13000

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a network problem. TCP ports might not be open over firewalls. Most firewalls are blocking all traffic on ports different than 80 and 443 over the internet. You should contact the network administrators of the remote machine you are trying to access and ensure that the port you are trying to connect to is not blocked.

Comment: What would be the most suitable port to use with this?

Comment: Talk to your network administrator and use whatever it is available under those circumstances.